# C Type Casting Issue (Float asserted to Int)

Tags: c

I was wondering why the following two prints in the image are not identical?

```
uint16_t linCalc(uint16_t adcAverage){
    float k = 2500 / 2500;
    float j = 8000 / 5000;
    int a = 1000 * (j - k);
    printf("a = %d\n", a);
    k = 1;
    j = 1.6;
    int b = 1000 * (j - k);
    printf("b = %d\n", b);
}
```

> ```
> b = 600
> a = 0
> b = 600
> a = 0
> b = 600
> a = 0
> b = 600
> a = 0
> b = 600
> a = 0
> b = 600
> a = 0
> b = 600
> a = 0
> b = 600
> ```

It seems that the floats are being asserted as ints before the expression is being calculated (I've also tried typecasting the floats as well in their declaration).

Comment: That is right, as you have it, your floats will be degraded to `int`.

Comment: Do _not_ paste images with code in your questions. Paste actual code.

Comment: Since `2500`, `8000` and `5000` are all integer literals, integer math is used for the division and then only afterward converted to float for the assignments to `k` and `j`.  For `b`, though, the subtraction between floating point values causes the multiplication to also be done with floating point, and be converted to `int` afterwards for the assignment to `b`.  So, different results.

Comment: @Dmitri Note: C calls `8000` an _integer constant_ or more specifically a _decimal constant_.  With literals in C, like `"abc"` and `(int[]){2,3})`, the address can be taken, not so with constants.

Answer (score 5):

They're not identical because `8000/5000` performs integer division, on account of both operands being `int` constants. The result of the division is `1`.

To force floating point division at least one of the operands needs to be a `float`. That can be achieved in several ways, namely (and in preferable order):

1. `8000.0f / 5000`
2. `(float)8000 / 5000`

Comment: Note: Suggest `f`:  `float f1 = (float) 1000000000000000000000000;` is a problem whereas `float f2 = 1000000000000000000000000.0f;` is fine.  Casting is infrequently the best approach.

Answer (score 1):

`float j = 8000 / 5000` yields `1`; rhs expression `8000 / 5000` is converted to float after its evaluation; `8000` and `5000` are literals of data type `int`, so `8000 / 5000` will be an `int`, too.

Write `float j = 8000.0 / 5000.0` to yield a floating point division.

Answer (score -1):

In the first case k = 1.0 and j = 1.0, and in the second case k = 1.0 and j = 1.6.
This happens because in the first case you divide an integer with another integer, so the result is an integer, and then it's stored into a float when assigned to k, and j.

```html
julien@ubuntu:/tmp/so$ cat main.c 
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
 float k;
 float j;
 int a;
 int b;
 
 k = 2500 / 2500;
 j = 8000 / 5000;
 printf("k = %f, j = %f\n", k, j);
 a = 1000 * (j - k);
 printf("a = %d\n", a);
 k = 1;
 j = 1.6;
 b = 1000 * (j - k);
 printf("b = %d\n", b);
 return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
julien@ubuntu:/tmp/so$ gcc -Wall -Werror -pedantic -Wextra main.c -o ben && ./ben 
k = 1.000000, j = 1.000000
a = 0
b = 600
julien@ubuntu:/tmp/so$
```

If you want to prevent that you can explicitly use floats (or at least one float) in the division:

```html
julien@ubuntu:/tmp/so$ cat main.c 
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
 float k;
 float j;
 int a;
 int b;
 
 k = 2500.0 / 2500;
 j = 8000.0 / 5000;
 printf("k = %f, j = %f\n", k, j);
 a = 1000 * (j - k);
 printf("a = %d\n", a);
 k = 1;
 j = 1.6;
 b = 1000 * (j - k);
 printf("b = %d\n", b);
 return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
julien@ubuntu:/tmp/so$ gcc -Wall -Werror -pedantic -Wextra main.c -o ben && ./ben 
k = 1.000000, j = 1.600000
a = 600
b = 600
julien@ubuntu:/tmp/so$
```